# How can I fix keydown delays in Javascript game?

Tags: javascript, keydown

I am creating a javascript snake game, and have run into a problem when certain keys are pressed too fast in order.  For example, (while going right) hitting the up arrow and then the left arrow key too fast will make my snake turn around completely and run into itself, ignoring the up arrow key press.  Is there any code that would make sure that any key press will always be rendered?  Thanks in advance.

```
let d = "RIGHT";
document.addEventListener("keydown", direction);
function direction(event) {
  let key = event.keyCode;
  if (key == 37 && d != "RIGHT" && d != "LEFT") {
    d = "LEFT";
  } else if (key == 38 && d != "DOWN" && d != "UP") {
    d = "UP";
  } else if (key == 39 && d != "LEFT" && d != "RIGHT") {
    d = "RIGHT";
  } else if (key == 40 && d != "UP" && d != "DOWN") {
    d = "DOWN";
  }
}
```

In separate function:

```
if (d == "LEFT") snakeX -= box;
  if (d == "UP") snakeY -= box;
  if (d == "RIGHT") snakeX += box;
  if (d == "DOWN") snakeY += box;
```

You can also see this problem by going to https://jssnake.glitch.me/ and playing around a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I briefly looked into your code. You render 10x a second, so if you manage to press more than one key during that interval, the described issue will occur:

> For example, (while going right) hitting the up arrow and then the left arrow key too fast will make my snake turn around completely and run into itself, ignoring the up arrow key press.

There are two possible solutions:

1. Run the render loop faster, so that no one can ever press two keys during that interval.
2. Do not store only the last key, but all keys that were pressed between since the last render call.
3. Avoid half-turns.

I think solution 1 is not ideal as you should *never say never*. So let's continue with number 3 (a hack) and then with number 2 (the correct and clean way).

## Avoid half-turns (alternative 3)

This little hack does not solve the root of the problem, but it will make the snake behave kind-of correct. The snake can move in 4 directions, but it can always turn only in two directions. You could either use a two-keys control to trigger CW/CCW change, something like

```js
let currentDir = "RIGHT"; //note I renamed your d to currentDir
let nextDir = undefined;
document.addEventListener("keydown", direction);

function direction(event) {
  const key = event.keyCode;
  while (~currentDir) {}; //wait until the control function is finished
  switch (currentDir) {
    case "LEFT": nextDir = (key === 37 ? "DOWN" : (key === 39 ? "UP" : nextDir)); break;
    case "UP": nextDir = (key === 37 ? "LEFT" : (key === 39 ? "RIGHT" : nextDir)); break;
    case "RIGHT": nextDir = (key === 37 ? "UP" : (key === 39 ? "DOWN" : nextDir)); break;
    case "DOWN": nextDir = (key === 37 ? "RIGHT" : (key === 39 ? "LEFT" : nextDir)); break;
  }
}

//and later in the movement control function:
currentDir = undefined; //avoid overwriting nextDir during this update,
// i.e. the while-loop inside of direction() will wait
switch (tmp) {
  case "LEFT": snakeX -= box; break;
  case "UP": snakeY -= box; break;
  case "RIGHT": snakeX += box; break;
  case "DOWN": snakeY += box; break;
}
currentDir = nextDir;
nextDir = undefined;
```

The four-keys version would work in a similar way, you can easily intergrate it to your code. The key is to use the pair of `currentDir` and `nextDir` and keeping `currentDir` constant over the whole 0.1s time between the render calls. But your problem would kind-of stay. A snake heading right would only continue up if you would press ↑ and ← immediately after each other.

```js
let currentDir = "RIGHT";
let nextDir = undefined;
document.addEventListener("keydown", direction);

function direction(event) {
  const key = event.keyCode;
  while (~currentDir) {}; //wait until the control function is finished
  switch (currentDir) {
    case "LEFT":
    case "RIGHT":
        nextDir = (key === 38 ? "UP" : (key === 40 ? "DOWN" : nextDir)); break;
    case "UP":
    case "DOWN":
        nextDir = (key === 37 ? "LEFT" : (key === 39 ? "RIGHT" : nextDir)); break;
  }
}
```

## Keys buffer (alternative 2)

The **correct solution** is even easier, but requires an array. It stores all keys pressed since the last render call in a [queue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queue_(abstract_data_type)).

```js
keysPressed = [];
document.addEventListener("keydown", event => 
  keysPressed.push(event.keyCode); //enqueues the key pressed
```

Having two or three keys pressed, you could virtually update the snake position inside of the 0.1s interval applying one valid turn in each frame. This could lead to delayed snake movement if you would be able to fill the buffer quickly with commands. It can be interesting to try out as a fun excercise. The movement function for the four-keys control would look like this:

```js
{
  if (keysPressed.length > 0 {
    const key = keysPresses.shift(); //dequeues the oldest key
    //if there are more keys in the queue, they have to wait until next time
    switch (d) {
      case "LEFT":
      case "RIGHT":
          d = (key === 38 ? "UP" : (key === 40 ? "DOWN" : d)); break;
      case "UP":
      case "DOWN":
          d = (key === 37 ? "LEFT" : (key === 39 ? "RIGHT" : d)); break;
    }
  }

  switch (d) {
    case "LEFT": snakeX -= box; break;
    case "UP": snakeY -= box; break;
    case "RIGHT": snakeX += box; break;
    case "DOWN": snakeY += box; break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need here is to delay the effect of a key press. You can achieve it by storing the last pressed key in a variable and only reading the key when snake is ready to turn.

```js
let pressedKey;

document.addEventListener("keydown", event => {
    pressedKey = event.keyCode;
});
```

Comment: Read the `pressedKey` while your snake walks at the point when it turns.

Comment: Could you explain this again please?

Comment: I'm not sure how to help, it sounds like I'd need to implement your game.